# Can't find tools.jar after installing JDK 7u3

Tags: java

I just finished installing the new Java JDK version 7u3 and now I am unable to find tools.jar file.

I know I installed the correct version "jdk-7u3-windows-x64.exe" and searched the directory where it's installed but didn't find the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which directory are you looking at? Default would be C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.03\lib.

Make sure you don't look inside JRE's directory, which is nested inside the JDK's

Comment: Looked through the directory and didn't see the tools.jar.  I just uninstalled and then re-installed java and found it in the directory you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

What tells you your missing tools.jar? if it's eclipse was your JAVA_HOME updated with the new JDK and your eclipse 32bit now defaulting to your 32bit JRE instead of some JDK it should be using?